# Visualforce Page Not Visible

Tags: visualforce, profile, change-set

I have developed a visualforce page and a controller for that. Then I uploaded the change set including both of them with the required profiles. But when the change set deployed in the production environment, for some profiles the page is not visible. I had to manually add the profiles to the page and controller to make visible the page. 
Where are the possible or common places I could be doing the mistake?

Thanks
Madhura

Comment: I still meet this problem and I don't kwnow how to solve it, any one please can help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use change sets to move components, the security doesn't automatically move unless you include the profiles you want to have security transfer for in the second section of the change set. (The section titled Profile Settings For Included Components.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick return Daniel, But actually I have included those profiles into the change set at the change set creation. I tried with `with sharing` as well in the controller. But still have to manually add some profiles. That's the confuse I'm facing

Comment: And the settings are correct in your source sandbox?

Comment: Checked the settings as far as I know Daniel. That's why I raised this to get to know where I'm missing the bullet. Still figuring this since limited access to production

Comment: If they can see the page in sandbox and not in prod, then there must have been a problem with the change set. Either you didn't include all components or some of the profiles weren't included in section titled Profile Settings For Included Components. Maybe you could post a sanitized screen shot of your change set?

Comment: could you share the detail info about the profiles you want to have security transfer for in the second section of the change set ? thanks a lot. @DanielHoechst

Comment: If I use Change Set to deploy VF with profile, the VF permission of the profile is also deployed. But if I use  Ant Migration to deploy VF with profile, it don't, the profile no permission of the VF.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is only missing for some of the profiles, you should consider what the difference is between the profiles that work and those that do not.  Are some of them portal users?  Do the profiles have different access permission to the objects being referenced by the controller?  Is it possible that changes to some profiles did not get saved properly in the Sandbox?  There must be differences, the trick is figuring out which are related to the problem you had.

Comment: Working on that @snugsfbay . My concern is, if the profiles haven't access to the objects, It shouldn't allow me to manually add the pages/controllers to those profiles as well isn't it?

Comment: I think Salesforce has to assume that if you are manually adding pages and controllers to a profile, you have good reasons for doing so -- maybe you plan to change the profile's object permission or maybe your code provides information directly related to a user's object access, including error messages for those who don't have access.